# Multiple first column in table next to others with regular expressions/excel function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Excel with values:

```
Caption | Num1 | Num2 | Num3 | NumN+1
aaa     | 10   | 20   | 30   | ...
bbb     | 40   | 50   | 60   | ...
...and going...
```

I would like to place [Caption] column next to each [NumN+1] column like in the example below:

```
Caption | Num1 | Caption | Num2 | Caption | Num3 | Caption | NumN+1
aaa     | 10   | aaa     | 20   | aaa     | 30   | aaa     | ...
bbb     | 40   | bbb     | 50   | bbb     | 60   | bbb     | ...
...and going...
```

I`m looking for your help to solve this with regular expression / Excel functions / VBA.

Comment: You just want the Caption column repeated between each NumN column?

Comment: @JNevill, you are right.

Comment: If the number of columns/fields isn't too large, I would just insert columns manually and use `=A1` to carry over the caption values to each added columns. If the number of columns is huge, then you might want to consider using VBA to perform the insertion for you.

Comment: Manually insert columns is not the answer I am looking for. Number of columns could vary from 5-10 to 99. I`m newbie in VBA, would be grateful for some samples of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Sub CopyColumns()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ' Your Worksheet here

    Set r = ws.Columns(3)

    While r.Cells(1, 1) <> ""
        ws.Columns(1).Copy
        r.Insert
        Set r = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Wend

    Application.CutCopyMode = xlNone
End Sub
```